# Refining Spring Field Injection by Incorporating Constructor-Required Parameters

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have created this class, and the issue is that I would like to create a constructor that takes only a JDA and a ScheduledExecutorService. I want the rest of the dependencies to be automatically injected by Spring.

Initially, I had a constructor with all dependencies along with @Autowired. The problem is that, being a Runnable, when I call it, I need to pass all the dependencies as constructor parameters. This becomes cumbersome as it implies that the calling class must be aware of and provide these dependencies.

There was also the possibility of putting @AutoWired on my fields but this is deprecated for reasons of nullPointerException in particular

I suspect I am approaching this incorrectly, but I would appreciate assistance in making my code cleaner and achieving proper dependency injection.

```java
public class YoutubeAlertTask implements Runnable{

    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService;
    private final JDA jda;

    private YoutubeChannelRepository youtubeChannelRepository;
    private MessageManager messageManager;
    private YoutubeAPIService youtubeAPIService;
    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(YoutubeAlertTask.class);

    public YoutubeAlertTask(ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService, JDA jda){
        this.scheduledExecutorService = scheduledExecutorService;
        this.jda = jda;
    }
}
```

```java
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new YoutubeAlertTask(executorService, event.getJDA(), youtubeChannelRepository, messageManager), 0, 1, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: `@Autowired` on fields isn't deprecated it isn't (and never was) recommended. The right way is to use constructor injection and if you need manu dependencies you might want to reconsider your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a constructor, you may find something akin to a factory pattern to be useful.

```java
public class YoutubeAlertTaskFactory {
    private YoutubeChannelRepository youtubeChannelRepository;
    private MessageManager messageManager;
    private YoutubeAPIService youtubeAPIService;

    @Autowired
    public YoutubeAlertTaskFactory(YoutubeChannelRepository youtubeChannelRepository,
        MessageManager messageManager, YoutubeAPIService youtubeAPIService) {
        this.youtubeChannelRepository = youtubeChannelRepository;
        this.messageManager messageManager = messageManager;
        this.youtubeAPIService = youtubeAPIService;
    }

    public YoutubeAlertTask create(ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService, JDA jda) {
        return new YoutubeAlertTask(scheduledExecutorService,
            jda,
            youtubeChannelRepository,
            messageManager,
            youtubeAPIService)
    }
}
```

Then you can inject the `YoutubeAlertTaskFactory` class along with all of the dependencies you want Spring to use DI to resolve, and your usage becomes a call to `YoutubeAlertTaskFactory::create(ScheduledExecutorService, JDA)`.